# Webservice in PHP + Codeigniter. REST X SOAP

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, soap

I have a question and would like to share with you to see if I can solve my problem. I have 3 applications developed in PHP with CodeIgniter, they all have the login / register identical, however each has its own database and your own files to login / register.

I need to create a single point of access to both the login and for the register so that the register in a system the user has access to all the others, then I will have only one database to store and query data from users. My question is: What is the best option when it comes to Webservice, SOAP or REST? I read that SOAP is heavier and slower, however also read that REST has fewer features. What do you suggest me? Login via Webservice safe?

Comment: I wouldn't say that REST has fewer features than SOAP, or that SOAP has more, or anything of the sort. They are both interchange layers and have as much or as little functionality as you give them. Personally, though, I think SOAP is needlessly bloated, and yes "heavier" as it were. REST relies on the same principles that HTTP servers have been using for over 2 decades now, and it's never not been able to do something I needed to do. As far as login via webservices being safe, I sure hope so, since I'm logged in to SO via Facebook right now ;)

Comment: Create a 4th database & add a table for users only, then create a view in every other databases that points to the 4th database/table so you can deal with it as if it's local database through insert/update/delete.

Comment: @ahmad Not sure how that relates to the question. Granted this isn't the sort of question to ask on SO, but I like the occasional philosophical dilemma every so often. OP, anytime dude. Hit me up if you want to talk about it more. This is one of those topics someone could debate all day long :)